# How can I snap lines together, but only when there is nothing in between them?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I am mapping arable field boundaries, to see where hedges might go. I already have lines drawn round the edges of every arable field. However this creates too many lines as it gives me a boundary around every arable field when in practice two fields mostly share a boundary and have only one hedge between them. I managed to get rid of all the overlapping geometries by using Union to break them into separate features and then running Delete Overlapping Geometries to remove the duplicates. However I now need to remove the arable field boundaries that are additional but not quite on top of each other. I can do this using 'Snap geometry to layer' then again Deleting Overlapping Geometries. But I want to keep double boundaries where they fall either side of a road or track, as in this case only it is possible to have a hedge either side of the road or track. I have the road and track data - Is there a way I can snap and then delete only those hedge boundaries that do not fall either side of a road or track?

Here is an image showing the hedges (in orange) with no road or path between them. The intention is to snap the geometries, and then remove one of the two overlapping features.

[image: hedges (orange) with no roads between them.]

Here on the other hand are hedges (in orange) with roads or paths (in yellow) between them. I need to find a way to keep both of these hedges so there is still a hedge either side of the road or path.

[image: Hedges with a road or track in between]

Comment: Without a screenshot it's difficult to imagine how it should look like - could you add one (or more) screenshot - or maybe provide even some (sample) data? That would it make easiert to look for a solution.

Comment: Thank you I have added some screen shots. Can provide some sample data too if that helps

Comment: Would it be possible to first snap all geometries (including where roads are) and than in a second step use the roads layer, create a buffer around it and substract this buffer from the fields using Geoprocessing / Difference?

Comment: This a very interesting idea, thank you. I will try it and let you know how it goes!